# How to split an array of words into an array of arrays where each inner array is a split string in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, sub-array

For example:

```
const arr = ['ab', 'cdef', 'ghi']

const split = [['a', 'b'], ['c', 'd', 'e', 'f'], ['g', 'h', 'i']]
```

How can I do that in Javascript? I'm struggling a little. If anyone could help, I would appreciate it.

Comment: map and split...

Comment: What have you tried? Please show your code.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) and [`Spread Syntax`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax):

```js
const data = ['ab', 'cdef', 'ghi'];

const result = data.map(s => [...s]);

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 0):

Map the items and using an empty string to split them.

```js
const arr = ['ab', 'cdef', 'ghi']

let result = arr.map(i => i.split(''))

console.log(result)
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply use `Array.map()`

```js
const arr = ['ab', 'cdef', 'ghi']



const result = arr.map((a)=>a.split(""));

console.log(result);
```